# Office Templates Web Service

Tags: javascript, templates, web, service

Is there a public web service available that provides free Microsoft Office templates based on user's search criteria? And if so, how are calls to be correctly formatted using JavaScript? And what format is the response file?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I am trying to find an online web service with relevant documentation on its usage, that provides various types of free document templates such as spreadsheets and brochures, etc, for use within software applications that I am looking to write. The web service would accept a search term for a particular document type, and return a JSON or XML file that provides a list of templates with images and descriptions, to be processed by calling application. I am open to opinionated answers.

Comment: Yes that isn't allowed according to Stack Overflow guidelines. Please read #4 http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have managed what I need to do. Just in case anyone else is interested:

```
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
<!-- Get Excel Spreadsheet Templates. -->
var url = "https://store.office.com/assets/templates/get?culture=en-CA&sourceIds=TM10000104,TM10000108,TM10000093,TM10000101,TM10000089,TM10000094,TM10000098,TM10000110,TM10000092,TM10000109,TM10000099,TM10000105,TM10000103,TM10000102,TM10000091,TM10000090,TM10000106,TM10000107,TM10000095,TM10000111&format=json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    alert(arr); // Process JSON response.
}
</script>
```